# How can I validate this Twitter Code?

Tags: html, validation, twitter

The following code is generated for twitter feed:

```
<script src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nutripak&amp;include_rts=true&amp;count=5&amp;callback=twitterCallback2" type="text/javascript" target="_blank"></script>
```

However this code is invalid according to w3c. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: You have to direct call this url in browser it will give you json OR use CURL of php to get json and then parse OR use OAuth library to get tweets [OAuth Twitter](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth)

Comment: I tried removing target="_blank". It works fine and is valid too. What about this?